# Notification doesn't work at Samsung Galaxy Note5

Tags: android

I need to show a notification when user do some actions on app.

I can get it working on versions 6, 7, 8 and 9, and some of these are samsung. But the Galaxy Note5 is the only device that doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = "channel test 1";
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle("My App")
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

I'd tried a lot of variations of that code according by another topics that I found.

The code doesn't show any error or warning.

Can it be a device issue?

**Edit 1:**

I got this code from [Firabase quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/8ab219cb636ff5f7e8f8fdf5f8f6f77b3094e0f8/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java) app:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue.

At Notifications settings, Samsung has an advanced setting that I had to enable too. The other devices has just one place to enable/disable app notification.